# Docker image size for ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile

I'm using following Dockerfile for ReactJS application:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install


COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

RUN npm install -g serve

RUN rm -rf node_modules

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["serve", "-s", "build"]
```

I'm installing node_modules, but I'm deleting node_modules after I run the `npm run build`. But still image size in GBs. May I know the reason please?

Answer (score 0):

use the alpine version.
the size only 38 MB (the "standard" is 332 MB)
https://hub.docker.com/layers/node/library/node/current-alpine3.14/images/sha256-2829f9b05a85038bd04412c45e5929f0005c64f8ae444e65ba4e02635f904871?context=explore

Comment: No @Zsolt Kovács , the question is, why the size is in GBs even if I delete the node_modules folder. If I do it with multi stage build, it's just 40MB.